# Is there any way to get all the AccessbilityEvents with AccessbilityService in a WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, accessibilityservice

I want to record and automate tests using `AccessibilityService`, but not successful with hybrid apps as I am only getting `TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED` and `SCROLL` events.

I have set following values in config xml file

```
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask", 
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
```

Code

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

            Log.d(TAG, " Event Received CharSequence text" + (event == null ? "null event id" :
                    AccessibilityEvent.eventTypeToString(event.getEventType())));
    }
```

I am expecting is there any way to get **`TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED`, `TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED`** events on `WebView` similar to native apps?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of WebView has some optimizations in it that reduce the events it sends under particular conditions. I believe if you get the AccessibilityNodeInfo for the WebView, that triggers it to send additional events.

Comment: I didn't understand, How we can use AccessiblityNodeInfo to send additional events? Can you please provide some code?